# Creating new json by taking url addresses from existing json and split it up Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a json file.

```
      [
  {
  "line": 1,
  "elements": [
    {
      "start_timestamp": "2022-10-17T20:07:41.706Z",
      "steps": [
        {
          "result": {
            "duration": 12216552000,
            "status": "passed"
          },
          "line": 5,
          "name": "m0e",
          "match": {
            "location": "seleniumgluecode.book.user_is_on_homepagee()"
          },
          "keyword": "Given "
        },
        {
          "result": {
            "duration": 2074982200,
            "status": "passed"
          },
          "line": 6,
          "name": "m1e1",
          "match": {
            "location": "seleniumgluecode.book.user_enters_Usernamee()"
          },
          "keyword": "When "
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "@Smokee"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "start_timestamp": "2022-10-17T20:08:12.284Z",
      "steps": [
        {
          "result": {
            "duration": 12090584100,
            "status": "passed"
          },
          "line": 12,
          "name": "m0e2",
          "match": {
            "location": "seleniumgluecode.book2.user_is_on_homepageee()"
          },
          "keyword": "Given "
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "@Smokee"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "Login Featuree",
  "description": "  Verify if user is able to Login in to the sitee",
  "id": "login-featuree",
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe/squad1/kitab.feature",
  "tags": []
  },
  {
  "line": 1,
  "elements": [
    {
      "start_timestamp": "2022-10-17T20:08:34.480Z",
      "steps": [
        {
          "result": {
            "duration": 11366098500,
            "status": "passed"
          },
          "line": 5,
          "name": "m0e",
          "match": {
            "location": "seleniumgluecode.book.user_is_on_homepagee()"
          },
          "keyword": "Given "
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "@Smokee"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "Login Featureefghfgh",
  "description": "  Verify if user is able to Login in to the sitee",
  "id": "login-featureefghfgh",
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe1/squad2/kitab2.feature",
  "tags": []
  },
  {
  "line": 19,
  "elements": [
    {
      "start_timestamp": "2022-10-17T20:09:40.836Z",
      "steps": [
        {
          "result": {
            "duration": 12761711100,
            "status": "passed"
          },
          "line": 23,
          "name": "m0e",
          "match": {
            "location": "seleniumgluecode.book.user_is_on_homepagee()"
          },
          "keyword": "Given "
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "@Smokee"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "X Feature",
  "description": "  Verify if user is able to Login in to the sitee",
  "id": "login-featuree",
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe2/test.feature",
  "tags": []
  }
  ]
```

I am getting url addresses in this array

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var i = report.length;
    var array = [];
    for(x = 0; x < i; x++){
        array.push(report[x].uri.split("/"));

    }
    console.log(array2);
});
```

This return me :

```
  0:
  (7) ['file:src', 'test', 'java', 'features', 'tribe1', 'squad1', 'kitab.feature']
  1:
  (7) ['file:src', 'test', 'java', 'features', 'tribe1', 'squad2', 'kitab2.feature']
  2:
  (6) ['file:src', 'test', 'java', 'features', 'tribe2, kitab3.feature']
```

I don't need **file:src, test, java, features**. Deleting them in 3 arrays and getting a unique array like this:

```
  0:
  (3) ['tribe1', 'squad1', 'kitab.feature']
  1:
  (3) ['tribe1', 'squad2', 'kitab2.feature']
  2:
  (2) ['tribe2, kitab3.feature']
```

Finally, if there are 2 elements before the .feature, I need to create a new array by considering 1 as squad and 2 as tribe. Like this:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdBUG.png)

```
[tribe1
    squad1
        elem 
             1
             2
        name
        url
    squad2
        elem 
             1
             2
        name
        url
tribe2
    elem 
         1
         2
    name
    url
]
```

How can I do that?. Thank you.

Comment: `in this json` that's not JSON, that's an "Array"

Comment: what is your expected output in json form? can you share that?

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. I made an edit. Array works for me

Comment: You are receiving incomplete answers because you haven't clearly stated what you expect as output.  The requirement to join array elements based on the uri is especially unclear. Please update the question to include the expected output as a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: I just want to get this array from the json code I have

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdBUG.png

Answer (score 0):

You should try destructing the array. An example is shown below:

```js
[a,b,c,d, ...rest] = ['file:src', 'test', 'java', 'features', 'tribe1', 'squad1', 'kitab.feature']
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: I added rest in loop and result :

    Array(3)
    0:"tribe1"
    1:"squad1"
    2:"kitab.feature"

    Array(3)
    0:"tribe1"
    1:"squad2"
    2:"kitab2.feature"
    
    Array(2)
    0:"tribe2"
    1:"test.feature"

i think i need to assemble this array now tribe1> squad1,squad 2
tribe2

Comment: Yes you need to change it according to your needs. Also please consider accepting my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform or create a new array based on input array with this simple logic with the help of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "line": 1,
    "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe/squad1/kitab.feature"
  },
  {
    "line": 1,
    "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe1/squad2/kitab2.feature"
  },
  {
    "line": 19,
    "uri": "file:src/test/java/features/tribe2/test.feature"
  }
];

const res = arr.map(({ uri}) => uri.split('/').splice(4));

console.log(res);
```